# MySQL Replication and Triggers

Tags: mysql, replication, trigger

I have stumbled upon an interesting MySQL Error message that I do not really know how to interpret.

The setup:

- There are two tables A and B.
- When data is written or updated in the table A, then a trigger is writing data to the table B.
- Operations happen on a Master database
- Data is replicated to a slave server

Now, whenever I decide to update data in table A, then it is updated and the corresponding log message is written to table B. MySQL, however, spawns the following error message:

> Note: #1592 Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement
>   format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. The statement is unsafe
>   because it uses a LIMIT clause. This is unsafe because the set of rows
>   included cannot be predicted.
>
> Note: #1592 Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement
>   format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it
>   invokes a trigger or a stored function that inserts into an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column. Inserted values cannot be logged correctly.
>
> Note: #1592 Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement
>   format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table
>   with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are
>   unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what
>   (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may
>   differ on master and the slave.

Nothing happy to the eye. How can I avoid these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of playing with the data the answer turned out to be NOT to insert data within a trigger into a table with an auto_increment column. Once I have shifted the id to be generated via the UUID() function all warnings went away.